# Direct product of two groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Also let $N$ and $\frac{G}{N}$ are non-abelian simple. Can we say that $G=N\times A$ where $A$ is a non-abelian simple subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Presumably you mean to assume $G$ is finite, so you should add that hypothesis to the question.

Answer (score 2):

$G/C_{G}(N)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the automorphism group $B$ of $N$. The only nonabelian simple composition factor of $B$ is $N$ itself ([this requires CFSG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier_conjecture)). Since the composition factors of $G$ are $N$ and $G/N$, it follows that  $G/C_{G}(N) \cong N$. Since $N \cap C_{G}(N) = \{ 1 \}$, it follows that $C_{G}(N)$ is the required $A$.

Comment: I am confused---is $G$ assumed finite?

Comment: I might be tired, but I don't really understand the answer. It could use some better formatting, at the very least.

Comment: @Stephen: The original question has finite-groups tag, so it's kind of ambiguous.

Comment: @tomasz, Ah, you're right. Probably the group is meant to be finite. Andreas' point is that for a finite simple non-abelian group $G$, the classification of finite simple groups implies that the only nonabelian composition factor in $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is $G$ itself, so every extension of one finite non-abelian simple group by another is in fact a direct product. +1

Comment: @Stephen: That would make sense if we know a priori that the extension is split. Do we? (I admit to knowing very little of finite group theory.)

Comment: @tomasz, I *prove* that it splits, $C_{G}(N)$ being the other factor.

Comment: @Stephen, precisely, thanks!